# GPG verification enabled, but no signatures found in Gnome Software

Tags: software-center, software-sources, appstream

"Software" keeps telling me there are updates but every time I click the notification, I don't get to see any updates because there's an error:

[image]

> Sorry, something went wrong:
> While pulling appstream2/x86_64 from remote org.pitivi.Pitivi-origin: Commit ...: GPG verification enabled, but no signatures found (use gpg-verify=false in remote config to disable)

Can I remove this remote? Can I add the GPG signature? What's the best thing to do from here?

Answer (score 1):

It's only Pitivi, so I nuked the "remote" in my local flatpak:

```
flatpak remote-delete org.pitivi.Pitivi-origin
```

That did then remove Pitivi (which I have since reinstalled from flathub, no problems) but keep that in mind if you have this problem on a more crucial application. There may be a better course of action.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by running:

```
flatpak remote-modify --no-gpg-verify flathub
```

then:

```
flatpak update
```